# Access store from inside beforeEnter

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I have the following in a file filled with routes

```
import store from '../../../store'

{
  name: 'auth.logout',
  path: 'logout',
  meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('logout')
    return '/'
  }
}
```

However in trying to run the code `store` is undefined. How can I access the Vuex store to execute the following code?

how can you also call a user defined action passing in the store.dispatch method? i.e. `logout({ dispatch }) { ....`

Answer (score 1):

in store.js, are you exporting `new vuex.Store` instance or just the plain object and aseemblyng it on main.js? And is the path ('../../../store') right?

Also, if it is a SPA, I don't see any point to have a '/logout' route, why not just have a logout method on your navbar component that executes the same logic (store.dispatch('logout'), router.push('/')).

**Off topic**: it has no sense to enter on a 'logout' endpoint with `requiresAuth: false`

Comment: yeah thanks....I plan to do that I'm just trying to isolate stuff to figure this out